# How to achieve Custom Object detection in OpenCV (Java)

Tags: opencv

I'm new to OpenCV and I need to find the state of an object. 
My use case is, I need to find CD tray status on a PC, whether it is in or out.

How can I achieve this via OpenCV? Do I need to train the OpenCV with positive images or is there any other approach? Can someone please help me on this?

Comment: Should it be invariant to angles or is your camera fixed? Should it work on laptop and desktop PCs?

Comment: Planning to implement using mobile camera / not a fixed one. But for the time being, I'm using laptop camera (web cam).